# The view through my canon 100D viewfinder is blurry

Tags: viewfinder, diopter

The title sums it up. I upgraded to full frame and when I reused my canon 100D I realized that I just could not see clearly through the viewfinder. Everything is blurry, even the parameters, even when the focus is clearly made on an object. The focus is clear however using live view.

I see well, on my 6D it is great but on the 100D it is very frustrating to just see everything blurry. Could it be something with the apparatus? (Else I suppose I will have to blame my eyes and the comfort of the bigger body's viewfinder)

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Is the diopter setting correct? Tiny wheel thingy next to the eyepiece (on Nikon cams at least)

Answer (score 3):

“Diopter” in optical jargon is a unit of measure in common usage by optometrists and opticians.

Thus the eyeglass industry uses this unit to specify the power of the eyeglass prescription. The photo industry has also adopted the use of the word diopter. The eyelevel viewfinder design has become popular. Your camera sports one;  you hold the camera up to your eye when composing your shot. Some folks are near-sighted, some far-sighted. Such vision problems are so common; the camera viewfinder has a built-in remedy.

A tiny wheel adjacent to your viewfinder lens allows the user to make adjustments that accommodate vision deficiencies. Peer through your viewfinder as you turn this “diopter” adjustment wheel. This will solve your problem.